# Google auth to Cloud Firestore with React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I have created Google authentication to Firebase but I would like to know if I can save the credentials(**email**, **username**) of those users to Cloud Firestore DB because I would like to have all the users saved in Firestore. Later, I would like users who have authenticated using Google email, to be able to edit their profiles, for ex. *change their name, add a phone number*, etc.

Comment: I don't think you ever want to be responsible for the user's password.  Firebase Authentication will handle that for you.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know that but what I am asking is if I can save user´s username and email to "Users" collection in Firestore.

Comment: You sure can do that.

Comment: I just found out how